# How to decompress this file

Tags: linux, debian

I tried to put my own server, updated the VPS, I downloaded the latest version of the Linux server, I tried to extract the server, and I came across a pink deviation.

How can I resolve this?

[image]

Comment: What is a "pink deviation"?

Comment: The right answer is there. Just for the record: your file is not compressed, the files it contains are packed together only without any compression. As a matter of fact, the size of the file is probably greater than the sum of the files that are packed. If you really meet a file that is compressed, its extension will be tar.Z, tar.gz or .tgz; then the contained files are packed together and the package is compressed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The behaviour of `tar` is correct.

You tell `tar` to extract a `*.tar.gz` archive (`z` means extract gzip archive) but you have a `*.tar` archive. The both following commands work:

```
tar zxvf abc.tar.gz
tar xvf abc.tar
```

Comment: Modern versions of `tar` are also very good at guessing the compression, if any. So leaving out the type argument will even work on most compressed files.